# OFFIS DICOM scope toolkit Structured report link to image

Tags: scope, console, dicom, toolkit

Does anybody knows how to create a structured report using dicom scope toolkit via console (ubuntu 16.04) with a link to a related image?

The thing is that I have an image of some kind of trauma and I have to connect with a report which is in a text file. The last file should be in .dcm format which contains annotation and a link to an image. I have to use dicom scope program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe others refrain from answering because your question needs a very long answer. I cannot provide step-by-step instructions, a few hints, though.

The way I would go is to:
(assuming that your image is available in DICOM format):

- obtain a sample structured report. I think that the "simple" Basic Text SR is what you want to go for. You can find some samples [here](ftp://ftp.dcmtk.org/pub/dicom/offis/software/dscope/dscope360/support/srdoc103.zip).
- convert the SR to an XML file using dsr2xml
- edit the contents in XML. Do not forget to include your image reference in (0040,a730) Content Sequence -> (0008,1199) Referenced SOP Sequence
- convert the XML back to DICOM SR using xml2dsr

By the way: From your question, I did not really understand why you want to use a *structured* report, as you wrote that your report is plain text. Instead of digging into the complex structure of SR, you may want to consider exporting the report to an Encapsulated PDF document which can reference images as well.